# PostgreSQL - Group by filter out specific rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have 3 tables in a Postgres 9.5 DB like below,

`threshold`

```
id    threshold_amount
----------------------
111   100
112   200
113   80
```

`customers` - each customer has a `threshold_id` of `threshold` table

```
id   customer_name threshold_id
--------------------------------
313  abc           111
314  xyz           112
315  pqr           113
```

`charges` - per customer there is charges so this table has `customer_id`

```
id    customer_id  amount  post_date     
------------------------------------
211   313         50       4/1/2017
212   313         50       4/30/2017 
213   313         50       5/15/2017
214   314         100      3/1/2017
215   314         50       3/21/2017
216   314         50       4/21/2017
217   314         100      5/1/2017
218   315         80       5/5/2017
```

I want to query it and return the specific `post_date` with `sum( amount ) == threshold_amount` by ascending order of `charges.id` column,

The resultset look like below,

```
customer_id   post_date
-----------------------
313           4/30/2017           
314           4/21/2017
315           5/5/2017
```

I've tried `sum( amount )` with `group by customer_id` and call the one separate the stored procedure from select clause and pass the `amount`, `post_date` and `threshold_amount` then created one temp table and insert `post_date` into it if the above condition get match and then again access that temp table but it seems something not valid so I want to know if some other solution or Can I do it in query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is asking about an exact match for the threshold.  This is basically a cumulative sum:

```
select cct.*
from (select ch.customer_id, ch.amount,
             sum(ch.amount) over (partition by ch.customer_id order by post_date) as running_amount,
             t.threshold_amount
      from charges ch join
           customers c
           on ch.customer_id = c.id join
           threshholds t
           on c.threshold_id = t.id
     ) cct
where running_amount = threshold_amount;
```

Comment: Okay, I will check it

Comment: Here in this case post_date may be any sequence so order by should be ch.id. Right!!

Comment: @NileshWani . . . You can order by whatever is appropriate.  The date made sense to me.

Comment: @Gordan Actually, If we have threshold amount 100 and charges are 50, 60 and 30 then in that case query not returning the result because 50 + 60 = 110 and the condition is running_amount = threshold_amount so condition never be matched.

Comment: @NileshWani . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  This question is *clearly* about equality.  If you have another question, the please ask it as *another* question.

Comment: Okay, I have done it by modifying the query and I have accepted your answer....Thanks for your answer

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
select
c.customer_id,
c.post_date
from charges c
join customers cu on cu.id = c.customer_id
join threshold t on t.id = cu.threshold_id
where (select sum(cc.amount) from charges cc where cc.id <= c.id 
and cc.customer_id = c.customer_id) = t.threshold_amount
```

Comment: Giving ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE